# Use A3 page on Highcharts exporting

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts

I'm exporting a Highcharts chart and a HTML table to PDF, but when my table is big, it cannot be placed correctly in the PDF page.

I export the PDF using:

```
Highcharts.getSVG = function(charts) {
    var svgArr = [],
        top = 0,
        width = 0;

    $.each(charts, function(i, chart) {
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        svg = svg.replace('<svg', '<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')" ');
        svg = svg.replace('</svg>', ' <h2 style="position: absolute; color: #333; right: 0px; width: 50%; top: 10px; text-align: center">' + titulo + '</h2></g>');

        top += chart.chartHeight;
        width = Math.max(width, chart.chartWidth);

        svgArr.push(svg);
    });

    tabela = $("#mainTabela").clone();
    top += tabela.height();

    svgArr.push('<g transform="translate(0,' + top + ')">' + tabela.html() + '  </g>');
    return '<svg height="'+ top +'" width="' + width + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + svgArr.join('') + '</svg>';
};
```

There is a way to use an A3 page when exporting? Or just use a bigger page?

Example of table divided by different pages:

[image: Table divided by pages]

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own exporting server and edit highcharts-convert.js file to adapt page size to your expectations.

Ref:
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was getting a height of the table clone, that is 0. So the height of my PDF always was the chart height, ignoring the size of the table.

I just changed:

```
top += tabela.height();
```

for:

```
    if($("#mainTabela").height() > top)
        top = $("#mainTabela").height();
```

And it's working now